# Will a dynamic robots.txt file that disallows crawling based on the time of day hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, robots.txt

We have a serious traffic issue on our site and we want to eliminate crawlers as part of the problem. If we disallow crawling using *robots.txt* only during some hours, will it hurt our SEO?

Comment: Googlebot may only fetch *robots.txt* once a day.   It isn't possible to have it obey *robots.txt* on an hourly basis.  Google's John Mueller warns about your approach here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86429/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Focus your energy on improving your site/server instead of trying some hacky workaround. You never know what time of day search engines will crawl your site, so only allowing them during certain windows may have a hefty negative affect. If you block crawlers when Google comes along, you won't like the results.

What you can do for Google is [set the crawl rate](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620). Limiting the crawl rate ("how many requests per second Googlebot makes to your site when it is crawling it: for example, 5 requests per second") will help alleviate the load impact without completely blocking them. If you have a massive site then this may mean a longer delay before new updates are indexed, but it's better than dropping off entirely.

At least for Bing, you do have a bit more control. As per their [how to page](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/crawl-control-55a30302):

> You can tell Bingbot to crawl your site faster or slower than the
>   normal crawl rate for each of the 24 hours in the day. This way you
>   can to limit Bingbot activity when your visitors are on your site and
>   allow us more bandwidth during quieter hours.

[image: Bing Crawl Control]